I need to return quarterly sums and year to date sums for each line item from Sheet1 to Sheet2
I would like to use Google appscript coding to:

On Sheet1 -indentify the last column that has a value
Sum that column for each row with the previous 2 columns (start w/ row 2.  Row1 is header)
Paste these summed values on Sheet2 Column D
After Finding the last column that has a value sum all the previous columns
Paste these summed values on Sheet2 Column E

Sheet1

Col A is Street
Col B is the first entry for all the streets
Col C will be the next weeks entry. The chart grows by columns each week.

Sheet2

Col A is zipcode
Col B is Street
Col C is Last Month
Col D is Quarterly
Col E is year To Date

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qA6L10kdhReW9JNksSQUPn2e24ZOdTOAnO25d-ksNos/edit?usp=sharing
failed attemps
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  var lastColumn = sheet1.getLastColumn();
    if (lastColumn < 3) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Sheet1 does not have at least 3 columns.");
   return;
  }
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var rangeToSum = sheet1.getRange(2, lastColumn - 2, lastRow - 1, 3); 
  var valuesToSum = rangeToSum.getValues();
  var summedValues = [];
  
   for (var i = 0; i < valuesToSum.length; i++) {
    var sum = valuesToSum[i][0] + valuesToSum[i][1] + valuesToSum[i][2];
    summedValues.push([sum]);
  }
    var destinationRange = sheet2.getRange(2, 4, summedValues.length, 1);
  destinationRange.setValues(summedValues);
  }


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  // Get the last column with a value in Sheet1
  var lastColumn = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  
  if (lastColumn < 2) {
    // If there are less than 2 columns, we cannot sum the columns starting from B
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Sheet1 does not have at least 2 columns.");
    return;
  }
  
  // Get the last row with data in Sheet1
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  
  // Get the range of columns from B to the last column starting from row 2 to the last row
  var rangeToSum = sheet1.getRange(2, 2, lastRow - 1, lastColumn - 1);
  var valuesToSum = rangeToSum.getValues();
  
  // Create an array to store the summed values
  var summedValues = [];
  
  // Sum each row's values from columns B to the last column
  for (var i = 0; i < valuesToSum.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesToSum[i].length; j++) {
      sum += valuesToSum[i][j];
    }
    summedValues.push([sum]);
  }
  
  // Set the summed values in Sheet2 column E starting from row 2
  var destinationRange = sheet2.getRange(2, 5, summedValues.length, 1); // Column E is the 5th column
  destinationRange.setValues(summedValues);
}


Your question is posted like a 'Service Request': You did not show what you have tried and you did not mentioned that you are struggling at anything. Also, showing expected output in the sheet along the your above explanation is preferred, in order  to avoid people asking you: what do you mean by this or that?

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

In your situation, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheet1, sheet2] = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const [, ...values1] = sheet1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const obj = new Map(values1.map(([h, b, ...c]) => {
    const temp = c.reverse().findIndex(String);
    return [h, [c.slice(temp, temp + 2).reduce((t, e) => t += Number(e), 0), [b, ...c].reduce((t, e) => t += Number(e), 0)]];
  }));
  const range2 = sheet2.getRange("A2:E" + sheet2.getLastRow());
  const values2 = range2.getValues().map(r => obj.has(r[1]) ? [...r.slice(0, 3), ...obj.get(r[1])] : r);
  range2.setValues(values2);
}

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

Note:

I confirmed that this sample script can be used in your provided spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

References:

map()
Map


fyi, you can do this even without scripts...

sum per row of last 3 columns:

=INDEX(BYROW(LET(r, Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MAX(ROW(Sheet1!A:A)*(Sheet1!A:A<>""))), 
 OFFSET(r,,MAX((OFFSET(r,,,,9^9)<>"")*COLUMN(Sheet1!1:1))-3,,3)), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))))



sum per row for all columns:

=BYROW(OFFSET(Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MAX(ROW(Sheet1!A:A)*(Sheet1!A:A<>""))),,1,,9^9), 
 LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))



Thanks for this efficient fix!  So appreciated
